# Define variable to to be type of record attribute pl/sql

Tags: plsql

Suppose I have the following code snippet in PL/SQL:

```
type my_record is record(
    CUST_ID   number(7);
    CUST_NAME varchar2(200);
);
```

Now i want to declare a variable which takes the same type as `cust_name`:

```
my_title my_record.cust_name%type;
```

This is what I tried and I get error 'PLS-00206:%TYPE must be applied to variable, column, field or attribute...I believe I'm doing what Oracle's documentation is showing...http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/type_attribute.htm

I'd prefer not to hard code the variable type, in the situation the CUST_NAME type is ever changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create variable of record type. And apply `%type` to this variable;

```
DECLARE
 type my_record is record(
    CUST_ID   number(7),
    CUST_NAME varchar2(200)
 );
 myRec my_record;
 my_title myRec.cust_name%type;

BEGIN
   NULL;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

see the very first line of the article, you posted.
it reads as **"The %TYPE attribute lets you declare a constant, variable, field, or parameter to be of the same data type a previously declared variable, field, record, nested table, or database column."**

Here you tried applying %TYPE on a record type and not on record.

```
Declare

Type my_record is record(
    CUST_ID   number(7);
    CUST_NAME varchar2(200);
);

my_var my_record ;
my_new_var my_var.CUST_NAME%type;
begin
null;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it the other way around. If you declare a variable first (using `%type` if you want), the record definition can reference that as `somevariable%type`. Or else declare a subtype first and reference that in both places.